# Converting three to four digit numeric values to 24-hour format hours:minutes in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have the following df (`time_df`) with one variable (`time_numeric`).

```
time_df

time_numeric
<dbl>

840             
850             
900             
910             
920             
930             
940             
950             
1000                
1010
```

I want to convert the `time_numeric` variable to a `POSIXct` in `%H:%M` format (e.g., `840` to `08:40`, `1730` to `17:30`, `2110` to `21:10`, etc.).

I searched older posts on Stackoverflow but still needed help to figure it out.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to tack a "0" on any of three digit times and then convert to a POSIXct object with today's date.  There are no time only objects.

```
times <- c(840, 850, 900, 910, 920,             
       930, 940, 950, 1000, 1010)

times <- ifelse(nchar(times)==3, paste0("0", times), times)
as.POSIXct(times, "%H%M", tz="EST")
```

Comment: Using `sprintf("%04d", times)` would be a bit cleaner.